# How to achieve "eval" shell funcionallity in Gradle

Tags: docker, gradle, minikube

I have a running gradle script that builds a Docker image (I use transmode docker plugin but I guess that does not matter for my problem). My gradle script works ok but now I want it to work with minikube so for that I just need to do

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

before running the gradle command. This makes "docker" command work with minikube docker, and not the original docker in my Mac.

The problem is that, as I run gradle scripts from eclipse, that "eval $(minikube docker-env)" command needs to be included somehow in the gradle script, as it can't be executed as a bash command prior to gradle execution in Eclipse (no bash anywhere). I have tried adding:

```
commandLine 'eval','$(/usr/local/bin/minikube docker-env)'
```

This does not work, probably because "eval" is not really a command, but a shell function that executes the return from command in $() as sub commands.

How can I emulate this so my gradle command includes the eval to configure minikube?

Comment: How did you solve this?